# What is the smallest number x such that $180\times x$ is a perfect cube?

Tags: arithmetic

What is the smallest number x such  that $180\times x$ is a perfect cube?

Comment: Hint: if a number is a perfect cube, then each prime factor must appear in the factorization with an exponent divisible by 3.

Comment: Presumably, you mean natural number, not just number. :)

Comment: I'm not sure, this is to gain some extra credit for my summer course math class and she gave us 10 questions that were taken from a math contest a few months ago from some very bright students.

Comment: I wonder if "zero" is an appropriate answer?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

We have

$$180=2^2\times 3^2\times 5$$
so we choose $x=2\times 3\times 5^2$. Why?

Answer (score 2):

$$180 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5,$$ So multiplying by $$x = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5^2 = 150$$ gives us $$180 x = \underbrace{(2^2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5)}_{\large =\,180} \cdot \underbrace{(2 \cdot 3\cdot 5^2)}_{\large =\,x} = 2^3\cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^3 =  (2\cdot 3\cdot 5)^3 = (30)^3 = 27000$$

as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$180=2^2 3^2 5$ so the smallest $x$ is $2 \cdot 3\cdot 5^2=150$